# Why can't I add to a List<? extends String> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

In the snippet below, adding "Hulooo" to the list generates a compiler error since String doesnt extend String.
However, typecasting an ArrayList of strings works. But typecasting an ArrayList of objects doesn't work.

Can someone explain why this is happening?
What applies to String(in this context) that doesn't apply to Object?

```
public static void takeList(List<? extends String> list)
{
    list.add("Hulloo");//ERROR
    list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list=new ArrayList<Object>();//ERROR
}
```

Comment: The first error is because the compiler is not smart enough to realize that there are no subclasses of `String`. Your provided `list` could be of type `List<SuperString>` (if `SuperString` somehow extended `String`) in which case it would create an inconsistency if you managed to add a plain old `String`. As for the second error, `? extends String` menas "`String` or a subclass of `String`", not strictly "subclass of `String`", so `String` fits the description, while `Object` does not.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. But do you mean the first error is anticipating that the list might have subclass objects of String, so that addition is not allowed? That's weird. What if it were a list of Strings after all?

Comment: @Brindha The `? extends String` means it might be String, or it might not.  It could be anything which extends (even though its a `final class`)  The compiler can't let you do something which might, or might not be right.

Comment: You cannot extend from `java.lang.String`... see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html: `public final class String extends Object implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence`

Answer (score 7):

The question mark `?` is a so-called wild-card operator. `List<? extends String>` means: any type `List<T>` where `T` is `String` or a sub-type of `String`. `String` is a final class, and thus there are no sub-types of `String`, but the compiler does not look at this. And thus, the compiler assumes that the list could be a list of some sub-type of `String`, and it would not be possible to add `String`s to such a list.

Let's simulate your example with a non-final class, `A`, which has a sub-class, `B`:

```
class A { 
    // empty
}

class B extends A {
    void f();
}
```

And now consider the equivalent to your method:

```
public static void takeList(List<? extends A> list) {
    list.add(new A());
}
```

This will not compile, for the following reason. Suppose you call this method as follows:

```
List<B> myList = new ArrayList<>();   // line 1
takeList(myList);                     // line 2
B element = myList.get(0);            // line 3
B.f();                                // line 4
```

Since `B` is a sub-class of `A` the function call in line 2 is legal. But the method `takeList` adds an `A` to the list which is not a `B`. An then the list of `B`s contains an element which is not a `B`, and line 3 and 4 break down.

The type system is there to prevent typing errors, so if there is one scenario where you could add an object of the wrong type to a list, the type system must forbid it.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer, make sure to log in first :P

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It wasn't me who tried to edit the answer, but the edit was correct. As mentioned in the line above the code, `B` was supposed to be a sub-class of `A`.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Yeah, I agree that the edit was correct; in retrospect, I don't know why I rejected it.