# Bounded wildcards in reference types

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have trouble understanding following code about two `Predicate` objects. The first one uses a lower bounded wildcard, the second a upper bounded.

```java
Predicate<? super String> p1 = s -> s.startsWith("a"); // why can I call startsWith()?
Predicate<? extends String> p2 = s -> s.startsWith("a");

p1.test("a"); // works
p2.test("a"); // doesn't work (why?)
```

What I don't understand about `p1` is, why is it possible to call methods from the class `String`, e.g. `startsWith()`? Why can I only pass `String` objects into `p1.test()`, I expected to be able to call it for `Number` and `Object` objects as well.

As `p1` behaves I thought `p2` would, but this isn't the case. I can't even pass a `String` object into `p2.test()`. This doesn't makes sense to me, because we expect an object which inherits from `String` (including `String`).

I think it maybe has something to do with the fact, that we specify the reference type rather than the type of the object itself. But what type is then used for the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's legal for you to call `startsWith` for `p1`, even though `p1` is typed with a lower bound `? super String`, because the type argument is inferred to be `String`.  The lambda expression `s -> s.startsWith("a");` is inferred to be a `Predicate<String>`, which is legal to assign to a variable of type `Predicate<? super String>`.

This compiles:

```
Predicate<String> ps = s -> s.startsWith("a");
Predicate<? super String> p1 = ps;
```

This does not:

```
// no "startsWith" on Object
Predicate<? super String> p1 = (Object s) -> s.startsWith("a");
```

The JLS reference is in [Section 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), "Type of a Lambda Expression".

> If T is a wildcard-parameterized functional interface type and the lambda expression is implicitly typed, then the ground target type is the non-wildcard parameterization (§9.9) of T.

Here, the *ground target type* is the type of the lambda expression, and `T` is the target type, which here is your lower bound variable datatype.  This allows the compiler to assign `Predicate<String>` as the ground target type, which becomes the type of the lambda expression.

Also notice that you can't pass a superclass object to `p1.test`, because you could (and you already have) assigned a `Predicate<String>` to `p1`, which takes a `String`.

```
p1.test(new Object()); // Error: can't pass something higher than String
```

As for why you can't pass a `String` to `p2.test`, when you have an upper bounded wildcard such as `? extends String`, that means that the type parameter can be any class that is either `String` or a subtype.  (The compiler ignores that `String` is `final` here and there can't be any subclasses of `String`.)  The predicate `p2` could be assigned a `Predicate<SillyString>`, assuming `SillyString` is a subclass of `String`.  But you can't pass a `String` to a method that could expect a `SillyString`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, why `p1` is working makes totally sense now. But I'm still struggling with `p2`. What is the actual type of the object, why can't it be `Predicate<String>` but only e.g. `Predicate<SillyString>`?

Comment: With `p2`, you declared the type to be `Predicate<? extends String>`, so it would be legal to assign a `Predicate<SillyString>` to it, which would in turn only accept a `SillyString` as a parameter.  It's not that only `SillyString` would be legal, it that `SillyString` could be there.  It's similar to [why you can't call `add` on a `List` with an upper bounded type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283197/why-cant-i-add-to-a-list-extends-string-in-java).

Comment: Huntro - the point that you may be missing is that the compiler decides what you can do to a variable, based on the type of the variable, not on the class of the object that it happens to point to.  In other words, when you declare `Predicate<? extends String> p2`, you're saying `p2` might be a `Predicate<SillyString>` (or it might not).  But the compiler assumes the worst, and tells you you can't pass `"a"` (which is not a `SillyString`) to `p2`.  It ignores the fact that you happen to have made `p2` reference a `Predicate<String>`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I now got it. The explanations as well as the `List` example have helped.

Answer (score 2):

When you have `Predicate<? super String>` that means the actual implementation of the `Predicate` is guaranteed to be able to handle an instance of `String`. Whether the implementation sees the `String` as a `String` or `CharSequence` or even `Object` is irrelevant, as long as it can handle the type. This provides flexibility in an API that *uses* the interface. For example:

```
void addFilter(Predicate<? super String> filter) { ... }
```

You could call `addFilter` with a `Predicate<CharSequence>` or a `Predicate<Object>` instance, it doesn't matter to the API. For instance:

```
addFilter((CharSequence cs) -> cs.length() % 2 == 0);
```

However, when the API actually invokes the `filter` it *has* to pass an instance of `String` to `test`. If the API were allowed to call `filter.test(new Object())` then the `Predicate<CharSequence>` passed to `addFilter` above would fail with a `ClassCastException`.

When you have `Predicate<? extends CharSequence>` (using `CharSequence` since `String` is a final class) you cannot call `test` because the implementation probably won't be able to handle any type of `CharSequence`. For instance:

```
Predicate<? extends CharSequence> predicate = (String s) -> s.startsWith("...");
predicate.test(new StringBuilder());
```

A `ClassCastException` would be thrown because the "real type" of `predicate` is actually `Predicate<String>`, not `Predicate<StringBuilder>`. Thus the compiler rejects the call to `test` because it's not type-safe.

I also recommend reading [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation why `Predicate<? extends CharSequence>` isn't allowed makes sense.